# Entanglement spectrum of a superconductor

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-entanglement, computational-physics, superconductivity, software

Consider the Hamiltonian
$$
H = \sum_{k} \epsilon_k c_{k}^{\dagger} c_{k} + (\Delta_k c_{k}c_{-k}  + h.c.)
$$
where $\epsilon_k$ and $\Delta_k$ are that of p-wave superconductor. So we have essentially a p-wave superconductor.

I want to compute the real space entanglement spectrum. So I divide the system into two parts A and B, and decompose all the operators in two parts. Then using these decomposed operators I write the Hamiltonian in the following basis
$\begin{pmatrix} c_{k,A}^{\dagger} & c_{k,B}^{\dagger} & c_{-k,A} & c_{-k,B} \end{pmatrix}$.
Then I use the correlation-matrix method described in [arXiv:cond-mat/0212631](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0212631) to find the entanglement spectrum. I compute the following correlation matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 \langle c_{k,A}^{\dagger} c_{k,A} \rangle & 
 \langle c_{-k,A} c_{k,A} \rangle \\
 \langle c_{k,A}^{\dagger} c_{-k,A}^{\dagger} \rangle &
 \langle c_{-k,A} c_{-k,A}^{\dagger} \rangle
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The python function for computing the correlation matrix is

```
import numpy as np
from mpmath import *
from Hamiltonian import Hamiltonian

def correlation_matrix(ky,n_cutoff,CA,CB):
    H = Hamiltonian(ky,n_cutoff,CA,CB)
    eigvals, eigvecs = eigh(H)
    U = eigvecs.transpose()
    U = U**-1
    N = int(len(U)/2)
    C = matrix(N,N)
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            for k in range(2*N):
                    C[i,j] += conj(U[2*i,k]) * U[2*j,k] * np.heaviside(-np.float(eigvals[k]),0)
return C
```

I do this entire calculation on the surface of a sphere so I expect to get a chiral Majorana mode in my entanglement spectrum. However I end up getting two counter-propagating Majorana modes. Can anybody help me spot the problem? Or guide me in computing the entanglement spectrum of superconductors!

Comment: Isn't there a contradiction in your use of the wavenumber $k$, which is non-local in space, with a decomposition into two spatially distinct parts?

Comment: You can define an operator $c_{k,A}^{\dagger}$ which creates an electron in the subspace A with momentum k. So the decomposition of $c_k^{\dagger}$ would be $c_k^{\dagger} = \alpha_k c_{k,A}^{\dagger} + \beta_k c_{k,B}^{\dagger}$ for some coefficients $\alpha_k$ and $\beta_k$. It is like writing a wavefunction as a sum of two wavefunctions, each of which is non-zero only in one of the subspaces.